# Expand square of a Sum into a double Sum in sympy

Tags: sympy

The square of a finite sum can be expanded into a double sum, like (fake latex):

(sum_i v_i)^2 = sum_i sum_j (v_i*v_j)

with respective lower and upper bounds. I am trying to get this done in `sympy`. This is how I start:

```py
from sympy import *
n = symbols('n', integer=True)
i = Idx('i', n)
v = IndexedBase('v')
vsum = Sum(v[i], (i, 0, n-1))
pprint(expand(vsum * vsum))
```

The `expand` function does not do what I hoped for. I can guess that the difficulty might be to "invent" a new index variable, `j` for the second sum. Is there something build in? If not I would be happy to get a pointer how to hook in my own sum-square expander.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any ready made function that does this but it's not hard to make one.

You can make this a bit cleaner and maybe use `Dummy` or `numbered_symbols` to create the symbols but I think this shows the general idea:

```
In [15]: expr = 1 + vsum**2                                                                                                       

In [16]: expr                                                                                                                     
Out[16]: 
            2    
⎛n - 1     ⎞     
⎜ ___      ⎟     
⎜ ╲        ⎟     
⎜  ╲       ⎟     
⎜  ╱   v[i]⎟  + 1
⎜ ╱        ⎟     
⎜ ‾‾‾      ⎟     
⎝i = 0     ⎠     

In [17]: matcher = lambda e: isinstance(e, Pow) and isinstance(e.base, Sum) and e.exp.is_Integer                                  

In [18]: replacer = lambda e: prod(e.base.xreplace({i:j}) for j in symbols(f'j:{e.exp}'))                                         

In [19]: expr.replace(matcher, replacer)                                                                                          
Out[19]: 
⎛n - 1       ⎞ n - 1           
⎜ ___        ⎟  ___            
⎜ ╲          ⎟  ╲              
⎜  ╲         ⎟   ╲             
⎜  ╱    v[j0]⎟⋅  ╱    v[j1] + 1
⎜ ╱          ⎟  ╱              
⎜ ‾‾‾        ⎟  ‾‾‾            
⎝j₀ = 0      ⎠ j₁ = 0
```

Making something that handles all possible cases for the limits is a bit more complicated.